# regarding the parameters in os.path.join

Tags: python

I am trying to reproduce a python program, which includes the following line of code

```
data = glob(os.path.join("./data", config.dataset, "*.jpg"))
```

My guess is that it will capture all `.jpg` files stored in `/data` folder. But I am not sure the usage of `config.dataset` here? Should the folder structure look like `/data/config.dataset/*.jpg`  The reason I need to understand this is because I need to create a data input folder to run the program. The original program does not share the detail on the data organization.

Comment: `config.dataset` should just be a string. So if it's value was "bob" - you'd end up with `data` as a list of jpeg files in `./data/bob`...

Comment: I'd assume that `config.dataset` contains remainder of the path to find the file(s) in. it could be as simple as `./data/subdir/*.jpg` or even `./data/my/sub/dir/*.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.dataset` in your code fragment is a variable. It's either a `dataset` attribute of some `config` object, or the `dataset` global variable in an imported `config` module (from this code's perspective they work the same).

As a few people have commented, for that code to work, `config.dataset` must evaluate to a string, probably a single directory name. So the result of the `join` call will be something like `"./data/images/*.jpg"` (if `config.dataset` is `"images"`). The variable could also have a (pre-joined) path section including one or more slashes. For instance, if `config.dataset` was `"path/to/the/images"`, you'd end up with `"./data/path/to/the/images/*.jpg"`.